# In TestNG xml file, How can I call another java method inside beanshell?

Tags: java, testng, beanshell

In TestNG xml file, How can I call another java method inside BeanShell?
Below is the script I am using inside testNG xml file method-selector tags. but somehow it is not picking any test case to run and not giving any bug as well.
validatePredicates is a static java method written in another java class com.myProject.TestNG.TestClass.validatePredicates

```
            <script language="beanshell">
                <![CDATA[return com.myProject.TestNG.validatePredicates(groups,"myGroup&bug");
            ]]>
            </script>
```

Comment: Are you trying to select methods that are annotated with `@myGroup&bug` group in your tests?

Comment: yup, The logic to select groups based on boolean expression is written in validatePredicates method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with the following method: `com.myProject.TestNG.validatePredicates(String[] groups, String testingExpression)` .
Actually I was expecting groups to be in String array but testNg passes groups in `hashMap`. So I changed `String[]` to Map and problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

Alternately , you can also use `<method-selectors>`. This can be put under  `<test>` or `<suite>` tags depending if you want it to apply  for a single test or all tests in a suite.

```
<method-selectors>
    <method-selector>
      <script language="beanshell"><![CDATA[
        groups.containsKey("myGroup&bug") ;
        ]]>
        </script>
     </method-selector>
    </method-selectors>
```